# Escrevendo codigos com python 3

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, python-3.x

Bom guys... Atualmente estou trabalhando em um projeto, onde em uma das funções o script tem que escrever um determinado código que foi gerado a partir de parâmetros escolhidos pelo usuário, porem apos ter gerado tal codigo e adicionado o mesmo ao arquivo alvo, notei que sempre da algum erro na identacao. Para fazer o mesmo funcionar tenho que ir ao editor e re-tabular todas as linha, mesmo que a tabulação esteja correta, ja tentei trocar de editor e ate mesmo usar o do próprio python, porem o mesmo erro retorna.

Segue código para gerar:

```
    def criarHabilidade(self, nome, classe, valorMinimoParaAcertar, danoMinimo, danoMaximo):
        habilidadesCriadas[nome] = classe

        habilidade = '''

def {0}(self, dado, alvo = "sem", estadoDoJogador = "normal"):
    dano = 0
    if estadoDoJogador == "normal":
        if dano >= {1}:
            dano = random.randint({2}, {3})
        else:
            dano = 0
            return "Errou"
        if alvo != "sem":
            resultado = alvo.levarDano(dano)
            if resultado == "Morreu":
                return alvo.nome+": Morre!"
            else:
                return alvo.nome+": -"+str(dano)+" vida. Vida atual: "+str(alvo.vida)
        else:
            return dano
    else:
        return "Impossivel atacar! Jogador morto ou sob efeito de algo..."

'''.format(nome, valorMinimoParaAcertar, danoMinimo, danoMaximo)
```

Segue codigo resultante:

```
#Habilidades criadas 007689


def oi(self, dado, alvo = "sem", estadoDoJogador = "normal"):
    dano = 0
    if estadoDoJogador == "normal":
        if dano >= 1:
            dano = random.randint(1, 1)
        else:
            dano = 0
            return "Errou"
        if alvo != "sem":
            resultado = alvo.levarDano(dano)
            if resultado == "Morreu":
                return alvo.nome+": Morre!"
            else:
                return alvo.nome+": -"+str(dano)+" vida. Vida atual: "+str(alvo.vida)
        else:
            return dano
    else:
        return "Impossivel atacar! Jogador morto ou sob efeito de algo..."
```

OBS: Estou usando orientação a objetos, e segundo os editores o codigo esta identado certo, porem sempre tenho que realizar o procedimento que já comentei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python possui alguns problemas com indentação e tabulação.

Quando utilizo editores de texto como o atom (e similares) sempre configuro para em arquivos python utilizar sempre espaços em branco no lugar de tabulação.
Utilize um número fixo de espaços em branco no lugar de tabulação que seu problema será resolvido.

Comment: Obrigado!! Assim que chegar em casa testarei!